# Upload photos from camera roll using AWS iOS sdk V2 AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Based on the example given on github, I could upload the photo to S3 by reading photo from AssetLibrary(< iOS 8.0) or PhotoFramwork(iOS 8.0 and later) and writing it to the temporary file.

I feel its redundant as I have rewrite the image into temp file before I could upload it using AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest.

I would really appreciate your suggestion to handle this scenario in an easy way.

Thanks,
Sahil

Comment: Please go through [github link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/42).